# Want to get all clicks with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 rows of div with 3 div inside. If I click on `#femme`, then on `#travail` and then on `#debutant` I want to see `.premier-choix-entree-quatre` and not the other choices.

To sum up, I want to record clicks one by one to target an answer. I hope that's clear and thanks for helping me.

```html
<div class="arbre-decisionnel">
  <div class="entree-un">
    <h3>Vous êtes...</h3>
    <div class="premier-choix-entree-un choix" id="femme">
      <p>Une femme ?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="deuxieme-choix-entree-un choix" id="homme">
      <p>Un homme ?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="deuxieme-entree">
    <h3>Vous souhaitez...</h3>
    <div class="premier-choix-entree-deux choix" id="sport">
      <p>Améliorer vos perfomances dans le sport</p>
    </div>
    <div class="deuxieme-choix-entree-deux choix" id="travail">
      <p>Améliorer vos performances <br> au travail</p>
    </div>
    <div class="troisieme-choix-entree-deux choix" id="general">
      <p>Améliorer votre santé <br> en général</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="troisieme-entree">
    <h3>Votre expérience avec le sport...</h3>
    <div class="premier-choix-entree-trois choix" id="debutant">
      <p>Débutant</p>
    </div>
    <div class="deuxieme-choix-entree-trois choix" id="confirmé">
      <p>Confirmé</p>
    </div>
    <div class="troisieme-choix-entree-trois choix" id="expert">
      <p>Expert</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="quatrieme-entree">
    <h3>Votre box personnalisée...</h3>
    <div class="premier-choix-entree-quatre choix">
      <a href="">Box 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="deuxieme-choix-entree-quatre choix">
      <a href="">Box 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="troisieme-choix-entree-quatre choix">
      <a href="">Box 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share the javascript code with your attempts?

Comment: also, have a look on how ask with a complete, minimal, verifiable example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please go through [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for detail, examples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would register one click handler function per event, so in you case 3.

Then, either have something calling a function that checks if all 3 clicks were already done or build that logic into each of the click handlers, at the end.

**State:**

I'm using global state for simplicity, don't use global state.
See how best to accommodate the state on your app.

```
var femmeClicked = false;
var travailClicked = false;
var debutClicked = false;
```

Then the handlers:

```
$('#femme').click(function(){
    femmeClicked = true;
});
$('#travail').click(function(){
    travailClicked = true;
});
$('#debut').click(function(){
    debutClicked = true;
});
```

Then somewhere, we trigger the last function:

```
function ShoulsDisplayPremier() {
   return travailClicked  && debutClicked  && femmeClicked
}
```

---

One more **very important thing**: write code in English! all this seems french to me!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already tried but the function return the first var not the one on the .click function

Comment: i dont understand. first var? which function do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

@Vetras

```html
    var femmeClicked = false;
    var travailClicked = false;
    var debutClicked = false;

    $("#femme").click(function(){
        femmeClicked = true;
    });

    $("#travail").click(function(){
        travailClicked = true;
    });

    $("#debutant").click(function(){
        debutClicked = false;
    });

    function ShoulsDisplayPremier(){
        return femmeClicked && debutClicked && femmeClicked
    };

    console.log(ShoulsDisplayPremier());
```

Here's what I done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get responses from the user and display something according to these responses. You are asking questions such as are you a male or female, what is your experince with sport ? etc.. So I think you shouldn't handle user inputs like this. You should use a form to collect user inputs and show what you would like to show according to these form inputs.

So for your example you can do something like this :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form id="example-form">
            <h3>Vous êtes...</h3>
        <select id="question1">
             <option>Homme</option>
             <option>Femme</option>
           </select>
           <h3>Vous souhaitez...</h3>
        <select id="question2">
        <option>Améliorer vos perfomances dans le sport</option>
        <option>Améliorer vos performances au travail</option>
        <option>Améliorer votre santé en général</option>
        </select>
        <div><button>Send</button></div>
        
        <div id="premier-choix-entree-quatre-choix" style="display:none;">
              <a href="">Box 1</a>
            </div>
        <div id="another-option" style="display:none;">
             <a href="">Another Option</a>
            </div>   
        </form>
        
        <script>
          $('#example-form').on('submit',function(e){
        
        if($('#question1').val() == "Femme"
         && $('#question2').val() == "Améliorer vos perfomances dans le sport")
        {
    $("#another-option").css("display", "none");
    $("#premier-choix-entree-quatre-choix").css("display", "block");
        }else{
        $("#premier-choix-entree-quatre-choix").css("display", "none");
          $("#another-option").css("display", "block");
        }
        return false;
          });
        </script>
```

Here for example if the user chooses Femme and Ameliorer vos performances dans le sport options than the div with the id premier-choix-entree-quatre-choix will be displayed. If any other options are choosen than it will display another option.

Comment: I am sorry but I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve if not this ..